# No path found on Django Channels

Tags: python, django, django-channels

I created a simple consumer on my Django channels application, but when i try to connect to the websocket from my frontend, i keep getting the following error:

```
ws_protocol: ERROR - [Failure instance: Traceback: <class 'ValueError'>: No route found for path 'messages/127.0.0.1:8000/messages/'.
```

Here is my routing:
**myapp>routing.py**

```
from .consumers import EchoConsumer

websocket_urlpatterns = [
    path("messages/", EchoConsumer),
]
```

**mysite>routing.py**

```
# mysite/routing.py
from channels.auth import AuthMiddlewareStack
from channels.routing import ProtocolTypeRouter, URLRouter
import myapp.routing

application = ProtocolTypeRouter({
    # (http->django views is added by default)
    'websocket': AuthMiddlewareStack(
        URLRouter(
            myapp.routing.websocket_urlpatterns
        )
    ),
})
```

And here is how i'm trying to connect to the websocket from my frontend:

```
var wsStart = 'ws://' + window.location.host + window.location.pathname
```

Can anyone help me find what i'm doing wrong, please?

Answer (score 0):

You are using path instead of url, just try this in routing.py:

```
from .consumers import EchoConsumer
from django.conf.urls import url

websocket_urlpatterns = [
    url("messages/", EchoConsumer),
]
```